# Homotopy of certain maps induced homotopies

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $\psi$ be a homeomorphism and $\gamma :[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a path. Now assumme additionally that $(\psi \circ \gamma)(t) \neq  \gamma(t)$ everywhere. Then we can look at the map $\rho_{\gamma}(t) = \frac{(\psi \circ \gamma)(t) - \gamma(t)}{|(\psi \circ \gamma)(t) - \gamma(t)|} \in S^1.$

Now, such a map can also be parametrized as $\rho_{\gamma}(t) = e^{i \alpha_{\gamma}(t)},$ where $\alpha_{\gamma}(t) \in [0,2\pi).$

My question is now: Imagine that $\gamma_{0}$ and $\gamma_{1}$ are homotopic paths, how can I understand that $\alpha_{\gamma_{0}}$ and $\alpha_{\gamma_{1}}$ must be homotopic, too?

I guess it has something to do with liftings, but I don't see quite through the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha_\gamma(t)$ just represents the angle made by the vector drawn from $\gamma(t)$ to $\psi(\gamma(t))$, which you could write down an explicit formula for if you wanted to.

Although it is true that $\alpha_\gamma(t)\in[0,2\pi)$, if you define it this way, it won't be continuous since it will in general jump from $2\pi$ back to $0$. You could let $\alpha_\gamma(t)$ take values in $\mathbb R$ to get around this, although all paths are homotopic in $\mathbb R$ since it is contractible. (If you want to also fix the endpoints, then you need to assume that $\alpha_{\gamma_0}$ has the same endpoints as $\alpha_{\gamma_1}$ which it won't in general.

I think the most natural thing is simply to think of $\rho_{\gamma}(t)$ as an element of the circle. Then it makes sense to ask whether $\rho_{\gamma_0}$ is homotopic to $\rho_{\gamma_1}$ for any pair of initial arcs.

Comment: If all of these suggestions are taken into account, in particular the suggestion of using homotopies with endpoints fixed, then there are simple counterexamples showing that statement that the OP desires to understand is false. For instance, $\psi(x,y) = (2x,2y)$, $\gamma_0(t) = e^{-i \pi t}$, and $\gamma_1(t) = e^{i \pi t}$.